# Jquery Single page Application avoid unwanted text between page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, single-page-application

I have a login page followed by a main page which has several "sub pages" in it. So once I login in successfully I always see a quick glimpse of all the data-role="page" flash by quickly.

```
project
   |-login.html
   |-main.html
```

In the main html I have (ignored the head tag, and some other tags for clarity)

```
<script>

   $(".animationload").show();

</script>

<body>
    <div class="animationload">
       <div class="osahanloading"></div>
    </div>
   <div data-role="page" id="landing"  class="app">
    .....
   </div>

   <div data-role="page" id="settings"  class="app">
    .....
   </div>
</div>
</body>


<script>

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".animationload").hide();
}, 2500);

</script>
```

What am i missing to make sure i never see unwanted text?

Answer (score 0):

I simply placed it outside the body tag and changed it's css by adding display:block and setaTimeout to hide the element.